# Object inside a object convert to single object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to flatten nested array object to single object.In my query i want to remove the source object and make the resultant object as one object (I have mentioned my output also).

```
    var result = [
    {"_id":"12345",
    "_type":"feeds",
    "_source":{
              "title": "hi all solve it",
              "link": "www.face.com",
              "content": "Hi thewwewewedwe asdasdasdasd",
              "createdAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
              "updatedAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
              "reply": []
                }
    }]

 //resultant array

     var newResult = [
        {
            "_id":"12345",
            "_type":"feeds",
            "title": "hi all solve it",
            "link": "www.face.com",
            "content": "Hi thewwewewedwe asdasdasdasd",
            "createdAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
            "reply": []
        }];
```

Comment: Yes, it is very possible. What have you researched so far?

Comment: I tried using reduce but didn't work for me

Comment: No need for a reduce. See my answer using a plain map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest version using plain JS

Handles more than one entry

```js
var result = [{ "_id": "12345", "_type": "feeds", "_source": { "title": "hi all solve it", "link": "www.face.com", "content": "Hi thewwewewedwe asdasdasdasd", "createdAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z", "updatedAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z", "reply": [] } },{ "_id": "12346", "_type": "feeds", "_source": { "title": "hi all solve it", "link": "www.face.com", "content": "Hi thewwewewedwe asdasdasdasd", "createdAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z", "updatedAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z", "reply": [] } }]

result = result.map(function(item) {
  var obj = item._source;
  for (var o in item) {
    if (o != "_source") obj[o] = item[o];
  }
  return obj;
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: All that code ... ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms where is yours? I did not use ES6 because it’s hard to read for noobs and not running in IE without Babel

Comment: Thanks for the answer mr @mplungjan . NAMASTE :)

Comment: noted @mplungjan

Answer (score 1):

You could use [...spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for that

```js
var result = [{
  "_id":"12345",
  "_type":"feeds",
  "_source": {
    "title": "hi all solve it",
    "link": "www.face.com",
    "content": "Hi thewwewewedwe asdasdasdasd",
    "createdAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
    "reply": []
  }
}];
    

const { _source, ...rest } = result[0];

const flattenResult = [{
  ...rest,
  ..._source,
}];

console.log(flattenResult);
```

Leaving the solution for result.length > 1 to you as an exercise.

Comment: And for more than one object in the loop?

Comment: What if i had list of nested object with same structure will this work

Comment: I will leave this as an exercise for you :) hint: use map or forEach or a regular loop

Comment: @deepakmasakale I have that in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lustoykov

Comment: try to research it yourself, this is not that complicated, you should learn to research yourself if you want to become a good developer. best of luck!

Comment: I will @lustoykov

Answer (score 0):

You can first loop through the array to get each of the object in the array and then loop through the object keys to get the `key` names. Then if you encounter the `key` with name `_source` then assign those object content into the flatten object using `Object.assign()`. This will work for `result` array with one or more than one object.

```js
var result = [{
  "_id": "12345",
  "_type": "feeds",
  "_source": {
    "title": "hi all solve it",
    "link": "www.face.com",
    "content": "Hi thewwewewedwe asdasdasdasd",
    "createdAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
    "reply": []
   }
},
{
  "_id": "1234567",
  "_type": "feeds123",
  "_source": {
    "title": "hi all solve it 123",
    "link": "www.face.com",
    "content": "Hi thewwewewedwe asdasdasdasd",
    "createdAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-08-08T11:42:40.073Z",
    "reply": []
  }
}];
var newArray = [];
result.forEach(function(obj){
  var tempObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    if(key !== '_source'){
      tempObj[key] = obj[key];
    } else {
      tempObj = Object.assign(tempObj,  obj[key]);
    }
  });
  newArray.push(tempObj);
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: All that code. And again you are answering a non-researched question. This is much shorter: `result = result.map(function(item) {
      var obj = item._source;
      for (var o in item) {
        if (o != "_source") obj[o] = item[o];
      }
      return obj;
    })`

Comment: @mplungjan why don't you answer then?

Comment: Read my comment to the question. We should not encourage asking "gimme teh codez" type questions. But if you insist.

Comment: Thanks @AnkitAgarwal